# How to use tactics in z3's SMT2 syntax?

Tags: z3, smt

I am interacting with z3 through its smt2 interface. Suppose, I write the following commands:

```
(declare-fun p () Int)
(declare-fun q () Int)
(declare-fun r () Int)

(assert (and (<= (+ (* 4 p) (* 3 q)) (- r 10)) (<= (+ (* 4 p) (* 3 q)) (- r 12))))

(apply simplify)
```

Now, I get a list of goals in the form

```
(goals
(goal …)
(goal …)
…
)
```

What do I do with it?

Another question, is there any documentation on this? Where should I look for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tactics are a z3 invention; so you will not find any official documentation on how they should be used from an SMTLib perspective.

In general, you don't just use `apply`. Instead, you use the method `check-sat-using`, that takes a tactic as an argument. In general, `check-sat` is equivalent to `(check-sat-using smt)`, i.e., using the `smt` tactic.

For your example, you can say:

```
(check-sat-using (then simplify smt))
```

this would reduce the problem to `sat`. The idea is that you can use these "tactics" to guide the solver to find a solution (or go faster).

Tactics are usually intended to be used from higher-level interfaces, such as C/C++/Java etc., and unfortunately they aren't all that well documented. Read through [http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~msagiv/courses/asv/z3py/strategies-examples.htm](http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/%7Emsagiv/courses/asv/z3py/strategies-examples.htm), which is using the Python interface, but you can use the same ideas directly from smtLib as well.

Tactics are also documented at [https://theory.stanford.edu/~nikolaj/programmingz3.html#sec-tactics](https://theory.stanford.edu/%7Enikolaj/programmingz3.html#sec-tactics), though again it uses the Python interface not SMTLib.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I know that tactics are z3-specific, so I thought there might be documentation by the z3 project on their SMTlib interface.

Comment: While your post definitely answers my question, my intention is actually not to check satisfiability, but to use z3's tactics to transform the original set of conditions into a simplified one. I've gone through Python's API and I still can't quite figure it out. I've asked a separate question on this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72606803/can-i-use-z3-just-to-simplify-an-smt2-file

Comment: Added link to "official" documentation, though it's also in Python not SMTLib. There used to be some web-pages on the net that had SMTLib examples, but looks like they disappeared.